# Multivariate linear regression : TensorFlow vs Excel

Tags: linear-regression, tensorflow.js

For my job, i have to implement some simple machine learning...
I didn't have a big background on math (so it's hard to understand what i'm doing).

So my first attempt to do something with TF, is to compute Multivariate linear regression...

I take this litte data pool:

```
    Conso,DJUclim,DJUchau
    171408,0,282.8
    151620,0.9,171.6
    164475,2.7,137.8
    153866,10,99.5
    162933,65.6,32.4
    188475,183,0.8
    210994,231.5,0.2
    222873,256.3,0
    179239,109.9,9.2
    159162,45.9,32.5
    158104,4.7,142.6
    174184,0.6,227.9
```

And try to found the best value for `X1`, `X2`, and `B` for `Conso = X1*DJUchau + X2*DJUclim + B`

With excel i have found :

```
    X1 = 118.734745
    X2 = 306.035978
     B = 140288,882921
```

and

```
    r_square = 94.8375%
        rmse = 5660.507380
```

Then I try do samething with TensorFlow ...
after +14k iteration i found :

```
    X1 = 118.689559
    X2 = 305.991638
     B = 140296.921875
```

and

```
    r_square = 94.8367%
        rmse = 4902.14502
```

- Why i don't have same value ?
- What is the rightest result ? ( excel or my ML ) ?
- Why Excel do this instantly and why tensorflow need lot of trainning ?
- TF for simple regression is too overkill and reduce perf ?